# Get which day of week a month starts on from given input of month and year

Tags: javascript, date, math

I have some JS code which stacks div's that are representing days in a month in a larger div that is actually a calendar. Users can freely select a month and year.  I need to build a calendar for that month.

For example: if this month is starting with Saturday then I need to first build 5 empty blocks and then start filling the calendar with blocks that have a number of day inside them.

How can I calculate this number for the given input of month and year?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get the day of the week by using the [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function of the Date object.

To get the first of the month create a new [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
var year = "2012";
var month = "12";
var day = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01").getDay();
// 6 - Saturday
console.log(day);
```

Since you count from 1 and Monday is the first day of the week you'll also have to do this:

```
day = (day===0) ? 7 : day
```

Comment: I'd like to add that if you want to use the month dynamically like `var month = new Date().getMonth()` make sure you add 1 `var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;` because the month in a query is 1 based but the return value is 0-11 based.. I learned this the hard way. heh

Answer (score 1):

ES6 way:

```
const firstDayInMonthIndex = (
  monthIndex = new Date().getMonth(), 
  year = new Date().getFullYear()
) => (
  new Date(`${year}-${monthIndex + 1}-01`).getDay()
)
```